# Scroll horizontally from an element of the dom using javascript vanilla

Tags: javascript, events, element, horizontal-scrolling, typescript

here I have a little problem I have a little level in javascript and I would like the page of my portfolio to scroll horizontally from a place in the dom how should I do it is a can complicate putting everything I did  here is my portfolio:
https://portfolio-rdw.000webhostapp.com/

For you to see what I want but I want to do it in javascript vanilla  no jQuery or others just Js  and here is the css code to successfully do this:
(sorry for my English I am French)

```css
#container .box {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

#container .box>div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 96px;
    color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
    line-height: .7;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#container {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
    transform-origin: top left;
    background-color: #999;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vh;
    height: 100vw;
}

#container2 {
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100vh);
    transform-origin: top left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 0;
}

.one {
    background-color: #45CCFF;
}

.two {
    background-color: #49E83E;
}

.three {
    background-color: #EDDE05;
}

.four {
    background-color: #E84B30;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scrollIntoView` function on a DOM element to scroll to it.

I took a look at your site structure and you can do something like below.
Just keep in mind to give each link the `href` attribute linking to the section id.

```
const navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar-nav');

navbar.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    if(e.target.tagName==="A"){
        e.preventDefault();
        try{
          const href = e.target.getAttribute("href");
          var section = document.querySelector(href);
          section.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
        }catch(e){
          console.log(e)
        }
    }

})
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

in fact I expressed myself badly I want my portfolio to scroll vertically and arrived at the section 'Experiences' that it goes horizontally when I scroll as with the css below but I want to do that with js only thank you for to have taken time anyway.this is not at the "click" event but by scrolling that it changes in the "Experiences" section thank you